# git svn move directories

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm working localy with git while our remote server is svn.
I had to move many files and folders within the working copy.
What I did:

1. `git mv SRC_FOLDER DST_FOLDER`
2. `git svn dcommit`

Now, the SVN repository contains the new files with all the old history.
However, since git doesn't track empty directories, and since I didn't use `git svn dcommit --rmdir`, all of the old directories were left empty in the svn reposirtoy and the new directories does not contain the old history.

Is there any way to move the old directory history to the new one AFTER I commited the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you how to do that with 2 tools: [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) (client side) and [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) (server side, here you need freshly cloned pure Git repository linked to your Subversion). git-svn doesn't support directories moves.

Both support directory moving detection if the most of the files have been moved into the same directory. Originally you could move the files and push with any of the tools.

Step 1 (option 1). You should revert your current commit either by replacement (make sure you have no local changes):

```
$ git update-ref my_current_branch <commit_id_before_move>
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Step 1 (option 2). ...or by reverse merge+commit of that particular commit (then no branch replacement will be performed)

```
$ git revert <commit_with_wrong_move>
```

Step 2 (option 1). Now you should re-apply your changes:
move directory

```
$ git mv SRC_FOLDER DST_FOLDER
```

Step 2 (option 2). ...or just cherry-pick your changes again:

```
$ git cherry-pick <commit_with_wrong_move>
```

Step 3. Then push your changes:

For SubGit:
for branch replacement (i.e. for step 1 option 1):

```
$ git push -f
```

for simple revert (i.e. for step 1 option 2):

```
$ git push
```

For SmartGit
press 'Push' button (if force push will be required, it will ask)

It could look strange that just undoing + redoing could help, but the main action (directory moving) is performed at push level (when translation to SVN is started), you should just do it with a right tool.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand, I can use only one of the tools mentioned. right? I prefer to not mangle with the server side if I can.

Comment: You can use only one of the tools (each of them will help), or you can use them both.

Comment: Another question: The changes were already committed to the svn repository, so is it possible to recommit it to SVN? Won't I get errors?

Comment: Good question. At step 1 you revert those committed changed so you get into a state you had before moving... But Git can't manage empty directories,so maybe "step 1 option 2" can lead to problems (I mean:the files will be moved back but the target directory won't be deleted --- hence won't be recreated),better use "step1 option 1" for the first step if branch replacement is not a problem for you(some people do not like branch replacements).If branch replacement is a problem for you it's possible to revert it only from subversion: "svn merge -r REV:REV-1 ." where REV is the revision of bad move

Comment: I might be slow here, but I can't understand how step 1 will revert my svn repository changes?

Comment: You revert the changes in Git (by setting reference to an older commit) and then redo changes. After pushing to subversion this "setting reference to an older commit" will be translated into an SVN branch replacement with an older commit. Maybe "git update-ref ..." is not the best way to set a reference to an older commit, but it's my favourite way and in combination with "git reset --hard HEAD" works very well.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I ended up doing "svn merge -r REV:REV-#" and then using SmartGit according to your instructions. Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Could you move all of the individual files and subdirectories back to the original directory (with history), remove the new (historyless) directory and then do the rename again from within an SVN working copy?

Comment: That's basically saying: "Do the whole work again using svn instead of git". isn't it?